# Box-Shadow over other element

Tags: html, css

I've this code and `icon` `<div>` `box-shadow` is over `icon-button` how can I fix that ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.edit-button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.icon-button {
  position: relative;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-top: 1px solid #f9aa22;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e29a1f;
  border-left: 1px solid #f7a921;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 3px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 19px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px .1px #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.icon-button .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 69px;
  display: inline-block;
  right: -36px;
  top: -1px;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-top: 1px solid #f9aa22;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7a921;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e29a1f;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 2px 3px 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.icon-button .icon-circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 23px auto;
  color: #e29a1f;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-button">
  <button class="icon-button">
    Shop
    <br>MYMARKET.GE
    <div class="icon">
      <div class="icon-circle"><i class="ic-link"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

here is problem

[image]

Comment: just remove box-shadow property from .icon class

Comment: buT I need this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pseudo on the `icon-button`

```
.icon-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 69px;
  right: -40px;
  top: -1px;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-radius: 0 2px 3px 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Sample

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.edit-button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.icon-button {
  position: relative;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-top: 1px solid #f9aa22;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e29a1f;
  border-left: 1px solid #f7a921;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 3px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 19px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px .1px #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.icon-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 69px;
  right: -38px;
  top: -1px;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-radius: 0 2px 3px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.icon-button .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 69px;
  display: inline-block;
  right: -36px;
  top: -1px;
  background: #fcac22;
  border-top: 1px solid #f9aa22;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7a921;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e29a1f;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 2px 3px 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.icon-button .icon-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 23px auto;  
  color: #e29a1f;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-button">
  <button class="icon-button">
    Shop
    <br>MYMARKET.GE
    <span class="icon">
      <span class="icon-circle"><i class="ic-link"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

*A note, pointed out by [John Bupit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019726/box-shadow-over-other-elemnt/42020471?noredirect=1#comment71215513_42020471), `div` element isn't allowed within a `button` element so I made the necessary change in above code, replaced `div` with `span` and added `display: inline-block` to the `.icon-button .icon-circle` rule*

Comment: Note that, according to the [current spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html), a `<button>` tag cannot contain `<div>` in their content. They must only contain [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/content-models.html#phrasing-content).

Answer (score 1):

can you change the `.icon-button .icon` `box-shadow` negative value to positive value like

`.icon-button .icon{ box-shadow: 5px 2px 19px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}`

not exactly `5px` it's upto you(any positive number)